# Difference between use and post, require and import in Express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm new to Typescript and Exress. I got a simple exported function like this:

```
export function testFunction(req: any, res: any)  {

    console.log(req.body);

    return res.status(200).send('OK');
    
};
```

And a simple exported route like this:

```
router.post('/', async (req: any, res: any) => {

    console.log(req.body);

    return res.status(200).send('OK');
 
});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my server's code:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import {testFunction} from './rpcs/testfunction';
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var testRoute = require('./rpcs/testroute');

export function initApplication() {
    const app = express();
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use((req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction) => {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    }) 

    app.get("/api/test", function (req:any, res:any) {
        res.send("Hello World!");
    });

    //app.post("/api/register", require("./rpcs/register"));

    app.post("/api/testfunction", testFunction); // Goes with fuction

    app.use("/api/testroute", testRoute); // Goes with Route
    
    return app;
}
```

It works ok. But what I don't understand it when I change

```
app.use("/api/testroute", testRoute);
```

to

```
app.post("/api/testroute", testRoute);
```

Error will be sent out...

```
Cannot POST /api/testroute
```

In the old node.js project I can do this just fine. But when I update this project to typescript. This error happens. Could anyone explain to me why **use** can only go with **router** and **post** can only go with **function** ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testFunction is a function that will handle the http requests. so verbs would work fine there, that is, get/post/put/patch/delete.

testRoute is not a function, its an imported file where in http (verbs) requests are handled. So, essentially you are going to "use" the imported file that handles the verbs. You are actually moving to a router level handling from an application level handling here.

Comment: Many thanks. This is what I've been looking for